# Tensorflow-alpha-gpu issue ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, cudnn, tensorflow2.0

I previously had cuda9.0_0 and cudnn7.1.4, I wanted to run tf-alpha in gpu,from this tf guide:https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu I found I need cuDNN SDK (>= 7.4.1) and cuda10.so I uninstalled previous versions from control panel and installed Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105.So, I should have imported tf succesfully,but not,I got the error.
And if I had

```
    conda list cudnn
```

I got

```
    # packages in environment at F:\Anaconda:
    #
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    cudnn                     7.1.4                 cuda9.0_0    anaconda
```

Though I installed cuda 10 and cudnn succesfully verified by running

```
    nvcc --version
```

I have anaconda installed and had previous cuda and I used tf 1.12.0 gpu ago and my gpu is nvidia 1050ti

```
    import tensorflow as tf
```

I expected it to import tensorflow 2.0 alpha gpu version

The error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python       
\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python  
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python          
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname,  
description)
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 27, in        
<module>
from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\audio                    
\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line   
49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname,   
description)
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "F:\Anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

my python version is 3.6.6

Comment: I found the solution, I reinstalled anaconda in my computer and reinstalled CUDA and installed the 10.0 version and everything worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:
**TensorFlow Version >= 1.13 requires CUDA 10.0 and TensorFlow Version < 1.13 (till TF 1.5) requires CUDA 9.0.**
See Software requirements to know more https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements

Also requires **NVIDIA® GPU card with CUDA® Compute Capability 3.5 or higher**.
See Hardware requirements to know more
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements

Hope this helps.